Restrict remote login through SQL Server Management Studio without affecting the applications
I have a SQL Server instance running multiple applications in our network using the username user1. All the applications are connected to the SQL Server with this username.
I need to block remote access to the SQL Server through SQL Server Management Studio with this username.
I tried Completely disable remote access to SQL Server guide but it is affecting the applications and they are getting network errors.
Can anyone help me?

You might be able to do something using a login trigger. The trick would be to somehow identify the calling application and force a rollback. I'm not sure if that information is readily available, or if it would be secure and can't be forged. As an alternative, you might be able to reliably identify the originating host (or IP address) and define a whitelist of hosts that can use a particular login. The real fix would be to use windows authentication with applications running under special service accounts

You're fixing the wrong problem. If users are able to do undesirable things via SSMS, that means that account has too much access, not that you need to block SSMS use. The fact that multiple applications are all sharing the same account is also indicative that you've probably granted too many permissions to that account.

This question is similar to: How to prevent user (having db_datawriter) from being able to connect via management studio?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Can you explain why you're trying to do this. Also, note that there are many clients besides SSMS (I even wrote one) so your measures might not be enough

We have more than 500 desktop systems in my organization and above 1500 employees using the application connected to SQL. One of my IT people, who knows the password, has been terminated due to unprofessional behaviour. It is not possible to change the password on all desktops as we are using the Winforms application. Therefore, I am looking for a solution to restrict the remote access of the SQL through management studio.

But surely this guy doesn't have access to your network? Unless he lives in the basement, Office space style. It sounds like you just need a firewall

Use a Logon trigger (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/logon-triggers?view=sql-server-ver16)
and rollback if
SELECT APP_NAME()

returns anything like 'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio%'.
APP_NAME can easily be set by client applications, though.
You can also check for HOST_NAME() to determine the origin of the connection.
